# Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside (Jwt ) Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, jwt

When compile this code, I get "Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.".

//index.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import { store } from './helpers';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { configureFakeBackend } from './helpers';

configureFakeBackend();
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store} >
    <App />
  </Provider>
,
 document.getElementById('root'));

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

//App.js

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Layout, Menu } from 'antd';
import { history } from './helpers';
import './App.css';
import { alertActions } from './actions';
import PrivateRoute from './components/PrivateRoute';
import LoginPage from './containers/LoginPage';
import Dashboard from './containers/Dashboard';
import Boards from './containers/Boards';
import Board from './containers/Board';
import NoMatch from './containers/NoMatch';


const { Header, Content, Footer } = Layout;

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    const { dispatch } = this.props;
    history.listen((location, action) => {
      // clear alert on location change
      dispatch(alertActions.clear());
    });
  }
  render() {
    const { alert } = this.props;
    return (
      <Router history={history} >
        <Layout>
          <Header className="header">
            <div className="logo" />
            <Menu
              theme="dark"
              mode="horizontal"
              defaultSelectedKeys={['1']}
              style={{ lineHeight: '64px' }}
            >
              <Menu.Item key="1">
                <Link to="/">Dashboard</Link>
              </Menu.Item>
             <Menu.Item key="2">
                <Link to="/boards">Boards</Link>
              </Menu.Item>
            </Menu>
          </Header>

          <Content style={{ padding: '0 50px' }}>
            <Layout style={{ padding: '24px 0', background: '#fff' }}>
              <Content style={{ padding: '0 24px', minHeight: 700 }}>
                <Switch>

                   <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={Dashboard} />

                   <PrivateRoute path="/boards/:id" component={Board} />
                  <PrivateRoute path="/boards" component={Boards} />
                  <PrivateRoute component={NoMatch} />
                  <Route path="/login" component={LoginPage} />
                </Switch>
              </Content>
            </Layout>
          </Content>
          <Footer style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>Abcd</Footer>
        </Layout>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
  const { alert } = state;
  return {
    alert
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

[image]

I used redux for state management.I don't know why it happened ?
There is my project folder.
[enter link description here](https://ufile.io/gdip8)

Comment: Well, you don't really seem to call `this.setState` in the code you have shared, so there is nothing really to be suggested. Can you share the stacktrace? Do you change location somewhere based on a security token? Any chance you could create a [mvce] so we could reproduce the error?

Comment: @Icepickle I added my project folder link. You can review :)

Comment: just move your route with Login to the top of the switch, and move the no match to the last position, that should do it without need for changing whatever you wish to do with the history listener, and you can still have unknown routes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

man it's simple, you have that code

```
<Switch>

                   <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={Dashboard} />

                   <PrivateRoute path="/boards/:id" component={Board} />
                  <PrivateRoute path="/boards" component={Boards} />
                  <PrivateRoute component={NoMatch} />
                  <Route path="/login" component={LoginPage} />
                </Switch>
```

in your app.js. you have a privateRoute withount path, just it :D
change

```
                      <PrivateRoute component={NoMatch} />
```

to

```
                      <PrivateRoute path="blablabla" component={NoMatch} />
```

but, to run that test, i needed comment you dispatch code

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    // history.listen((location, action) => {
    //   // clear alert on location change
    //   dispatch(alertActions.clear());
    // });
  }
```

i think have better way to use dispatch, just search

i hope it useful :D:D:D